# Inserting value into a new column: ValueError

Tags: python, pandas

I would need to create a new column based on a condition which come from another column.
Specifically I have three columns:

```
ID  Bought   Sold
123 True     True
143 False    False
154 False    True
21  False    True
```

I would like to create a new column (`Amount`) as follows:

```
if Sold=True then assign 10
if Sold=False then assign 0

df['Amount'] = np.where(df['Sold'] == True, 10, 0)
```

but it is not working. I got the following error:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Could you please tell me how I can create this new column and assigning the values?

Comment: Works fine with the sample data. Also `df['Amount'] = np.where(df['Sold'], 10, 0)` works as well.

Comment: what is your python and pandas versions?

Comment: @mrbTT: python 3.7.1 Pandas version: 1.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Python's Pandas, to compare Booleans you don't have use operators such as `==` or `is`. You can use directly the column for True and ~ (opposite) for False:

```
# You want all values that are True:
df[df['Sold']]

# You want all values that are False:
df[~df['Sold']]
```

**So, what you need is just:**

```
df['Amount'] = np.where(df['Sold'], 10, 0)
# the opposite should go as 
# df['Amount'] = np.where(df['Sold'], 0, 10)
```

to use operators == or is you can just state the column (True) or not column (False) or, just for pandas ~ column (False)

Comment: This is not correct. `df['Sold'] == True` works and, in this case, is identical to `df['Sold']`.

Comment: Thank you so much for comment and answers. I have got the following error after using @mrbTT solution: `/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.` Do you know what  it means?

Comment: Yes, it's just a warning, not an error. It means you're trying to set a value where there is already a value (the column 'Amount' was there with some values, and you were replacing everything with the solution. if you del df['Amount'] first, you'll see the warning doesn't come up.)

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this (it is a bit more verbose though!)

```
df['Amount'] = 0
df.loc[df['Sold'],'Amount'] = 10
```